# Is sizeof() recursive?

Tags: c++, struct, sizeof

The answer should be simple, but I wanted to make sure.

Is `sizeof()` recursive? For instance,

```
struct foo
{
   DWORD a;
   DWORD b;
};

struct bar
{
   DWORD c;
   foo d;
};
```

would a `sizeof(bar)` include the size of `foo`, returning a full 12 bytes (assuming DWORD is 4 bytes)?

Comment: It would have been quite easy to try this out for yourself, wouldn't it?

Comment: Indeed; however I figured since google didn't give any extra if's, and's or but's (i.e. 'certain compilers do x', etc.) and didn't forwardly answer it, I figured it'd be a good q/a to have publicly available if someone wanted a quick answer. I know I could have tested this in a matter of seconds ;)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: No. It would just tell you that your compiler made it 12 bytes. But since a compiler may insert padding, that answer cannot be generalized.

Comment: Under what rule would the compiler be obliged to include `DWORD c` but not `foo d` in `sizeof(bar)`? That looks like a very arbitrary distinction to make. (The C++ rule is that all members are included, as are all non-empty base classes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes... `sizeof` gives a total of all the members directly included in the type, including `struct`/`class` data members, non-virtual base classes, some implementation-defined links/counters tracking virtual bases, virtual dispatch table pointers, padding that helps align data members for CPU-safe or -efficient access, and theoretically anything else the implementation may feel like putting in there!  (for example, something for run-time debugging / error detection, non-Standard support of garbage collection...)

Of course, it doesn't include the size of pointed-to or referenced objects, but does include the size of those pointers and references.

Comment: +1 for *"theoretically anything else the implementation may feel like putting in there!"*

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the **[sizeof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s7x1k91%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**  operator gives you size of the structure including all its members.

But note that an compiler may add its own padding, so actual size *may/may not* be equal to sum of sizes of structure members.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is. Excerpt from ISO/IEC 9899:TC3:

> When applied to an operand that has structure or union type, the result is *the total number of bytes* in such an object, including internal and trailing padding.

(emphasis mine)